# Are there any http proxies like fiddler or wireshark on android?

Tags: android, proxy, fiddler, http-proxy

I need to see what page an Android App is calling from my device. Are there any Apps like Fiddler or Wireshark to see what´s happening behind?

Comment: This question is off-topic here as asking for a tool. This should have been asked on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @CliffBurton yes it should... but you just forget to see the date when the question was asked... there was no Software Recommendation on that date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I normally use a laptop with Wireshark instead of trying to capture on the device:

[Working link from web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20110312083510/http://droidhacks.com:80/2009/06/monitoring-network-traffic-using-os-x/)
[<del>http://droidhacks.com/2009/06/monitoring-network-traffic-using-os-x/</del>](http://droidhacks.com/2009/06/monitoring-network-traffic-using-os-x/) (dead link)

Setup the laptop to serve as the access point for the device and you can capture everything going on, and the wireshark display for the data is pretty rich.

Comment: This answer is a good example of why pertinent pieces from the article should be copied. 

 • Install Wireshark

 • Follow the instructions in the readme to also install the ChmodBPF script

 • Under Sharing area of the OS X settings app configure your system to use an ethernet connection and share it out to wifi clients

 • Now configure your device to connect to the wifi network provided by your system, test to make sure it works

 • Startup Wireshark and set it to capture traffic (wifi is en1 on MacBook Pro systems, what I normally use)

from waybackmachine: http://goo.gl/6mXcpD

Comment: I have tried connection the Android using your suggested link but I am unable to browse internet.

Comment: @SreekumarP no, if anything it needs a Windows machine.

Answer (score 6):

If your Android device supports a proxy (apparently there are apps for that), you can just use Fiddler. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/01/09/debugging-windows-phone-7-device-traffic-with-fiddler.aspx for equivalent instructions for Windows Phone 7.

Comment: Related: I wrote up instructions for using Fiddler with an Android device: http://www.cantoni.org/2011/06/28/debug-http-android-fiddler

Comment: FYI: I wrote up an updated guide with steps and screenshots here: [Capture Android Mobile Web Traffic With Fiddler](http://www.cantoni.org/2013/11/06/capture-android-web-traffic-fiddler). Also the Fiddler website has a good writeup: [Configure Fiddler for Android / Google Nexus 7](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid)

Comment: @BrianC Nice tutorial! You might want to add one hint though: Chrome does **not** use the normal WiFi proxy for HTTP requests if the option `Reduce data usage` under `Chrome-->Settings-->Bandwidth management` is activated. If it is activated, Chrome will use a Google proxy to reduce the data usage and will therefore ignore the custom proxy.

Comment: @ComFreek thanks for pointing that out! I've updated my tutorial page to mention that for Google Chrome users.

Answer (score 2):

You can find how to configure Android emulator and Fiddler to watch http requests and responses here: http://vkosinets.com/blog/2011/08/16/debug-http-requests-from-android-emulator