# How to check or find any android application embeded website

Tags: android

I have one application, and I want to know which website is used/embeded in that. I can check by disconnecting my connection so that an error showed like https://www.example.com refused to connect or something like that but it shoews me custom sms.

So is there any way to check which website is used in webview...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest, easies and most straigt forward way is:

1. Connect the Device with USB to your computer (accept all security permissions)
2. Open Chrome and type `chrome://inspect/#devices`
3. Select your device and app, Click on 'inspect'
4. Now you are in the Chrome remote Debugger. Open the 'Network' tab and inspect the network traffic

et voilà!

Comment: thats great solution but another problem is that my mobile can not connect to my laptop shows some error...So if any other solution like that without wire

Comment: It is possible do the same debugging over WLAN. But the first time setup is more complicated. Can not give you support out of the box for it, right now.

Comment: Here is a Thread for Wi-Fi debugging on Android: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi after you set it up the process should be the same

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly you want to know which URL the app connects to from a WebView. In this case you can use tools like Charles (https://www.charlesproxy.com) or Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to sniff the traffic.

For details see this question [Are there any http proxies like fiddler or wireshark on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752978/are-there-any-http-proxies-like-fiddler-or-wireshark-on-android)